# What is wrong when trigger resizing event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try automatic trigger resize event, I see it doesn't works. Then I make a test like below:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script src="jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <p>foo</p>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(window).trigger('resize');
            window.onresize = resize;
            function resize() {
                alert("resize event detected!");
            }
        </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

I don't see any alert (It mean that I can't trigger windows resize event). **Why below line of code doesn't work?**

```
$(window).trigger('resize');
```

Comment: same code tired it is working http://jsfiddle.net/06h8nzmf/

Comment: My ultimate purpose is how to make `$(window).trigger('resize');` works.

Comment: @raghavendra that doesn't work. The resize event isn't **manually triggered**. `$(window).trigger('resize');` in your demo does nothing.

Comment: alert won't come in sandbox. try in new html page it is working

Comment: @raghavendra that's because `$(window).trigger('resize');` isn't doing anything, which is OP's problem, see my answer (linked in the comment above) and you'll see why.

Comment: Why would people give -2 for the first working answer!

Answer (score 1):

It's because of your ordering. You're triggering the resize event *before* assigning the `resize` function to `window.onresize`.

Simply change the ordering to:

```js
window.onresize = resize;
$(window).trigger('resize');
function resize() {
  alert("resize event detected!");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @JamesDonnelly why does it works in fiddle? . Curious

Comment: @TributetoAPJKalamSir OP's code? It doesn't. Not until the result frame is resized, anyway. By that point `window.onresize = resize;` has been called. The manual `$(window).trigger('resize');` in the question is called but doesn't trigger the `resize()` function.

Answer (score 1):

@James Donnelly has provided the answer for your hoisting problem.

But I would like to add another way to use the code since you're using jQuery:

```
$(window).on('resize',resizefunc).resize();
function resizefunc() {
  alert("resize event detected!");
}
```

Notice that I have renamed your resize function to resizefunc to avoid confusion in resize method of jquery.

Answer (score 0):

You have triggered the `resize` before it was attached to the window object. Please try to code below:

```
function resize() {
   alert("Resize event detected!");
}

$(window).on("resize", resize)
         .trigger('resize');
```

Comment: Why would people give -2 for the first working answer!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try this:

```
$(window).on('resize',
            function resize() {
                alert("resize event detected!");
            });
```

if you just want to trigger you have to put $(window).trigger('resize'); AFTER the code I posted before

Answer (score 0):

Since the native events are asynchronous, we could suppose that your code should work.

However the `.trigger` method not throws native events but it emulates them. In most cases `jQuery` call the function synchronously, then the order of your calls matter (as suggested by other answers)